# Perl regex to remove empty strings

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write regex to remove empty strings on a line (and doesn't care about whitespace between list items), for example: `baz foo,   "","", bar, ""` becomes `baz foo, bar`

So far I'm trying

```
$newLine =~ s/""\s*?,//g;
$newLine =~ s/,\s*?""//g;
```

but given `baz "", foo, ""` it is returning `baz  foo, ""`, but I want it to return `baz foo`.

Could anyone explain what's going wrong/how I can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me:

```
$string = 'baz "", foo, ""';
$string =~ s/""\s*?,//g;
$string =~ s/,\s*?""//g;
print "$string\n";
```

Returns

```
baz  foo
```

for me.

Edit: As stated in the commentary below, it won't work for the string `baz "", ""`. That's because the first regex consumes the `,` right before the second `""`, causing the second regex to not match.

An alternative for the regexes would be to use `map`.

```
$string = 'baz "", "", foo';
$string = join(" ", map { $_ =~ s/\s*""\s*//g; $_; } (split(/\s*,\s*/, $string)));
```

That will set `$string` to `baz foo`

Comment: Well, it did for me, using the code he provided. It returned exactly what he describes as his needed output from the input `baz "", foo, ""`.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Okay, I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to split the string, remove elements that don't contain anything apart from `""` (and possibly surrounding spaces) and join those back.

The following might work for you:

```
@foo = grep { !/\s?""\s?/ } split /,/, $newLine;
$newLine = join(',', @foo);
```

Example:

```
$ cat mmm
$newLine = 'baz foo, "","", bar, ""';
@foo = grep { !/\s?""\s?/ } split /,/, $newLine;
$newLine = join(',', @foo);
print $newLine . "\n";
$ perl mmm
baz foo, bar
```